# date and integer addition in django F object

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying retrieve objects with the following model

```
Tools:
    last_calibration_date: Date
    period:Integer
    .
    .
```

Now to get all expired tools, I want to perform a query which does something like `last_calibration_date + period < current_date`

How can this be done using django ORM? Its easy with raw query. I am trying something like

```
.filter(last_calibration_date__gte = date.today()+ timedelta(F('calibration_period')*30))
```

Not working! Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `F` objects don't work that way. You need to use `extra()` - for instance, using MySQL:

```
.extra(where=['period + last_calibration_date < CURDATE()']
```